# How to bind a single listview columns with multiple db tables using Wpf

Tags: c#, wpf, database, silverlight, listview

Note : The above question is not the same as my question .

How it is possible to make one list-view to display columns from multiple table?
Here is my list view

```
<ListView x:Name="lvac" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="380" Margin="23,180,0,0" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=''}" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="949">
        <ListView.View>
            <GridView>
                <GridViewColumn Width="100"  Header="Date" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=Dated}" />
                <GridViewColumn Width="120"  Header="Transaction Description" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=AreaLocation}" />
                <GridViewColumn Width="100" Header="Amount In" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=Amountin}" /> 
                <GridViewColumn Width="100" Header="Amount Out" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=Amountout}" /> 
                <GridViewColumn Width="100" Header="Balance" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=Bbalance}" />
            </GridView>
        </ListView.View>
    </ListView>
```

My all columns of list-view belong to "BankAccount" except last column that belong to "Bank".How i can make this possible ?thanks

Note : here i am not using any frame work .

Comment: no ..that question is binding one list view to one tables and at run-time replacing that table with new one....my question is to bind columns of one list view to multiple table at compile time .

Comment: Please Note: above duplicate question is not the same as my question ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `ListView.ItemsSource` property can bind to one collection item. So, there is no direct way to achieve this. But, you can create a class that encapsulates all the values you want to display in the ListView. Then create an ObservableCollection and bind it to the ListView.ItemSource.

Note: You can achieve this in much cleaner way if you follow any UI patterns. However, just to keep it simple

```
/// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            _dataItems = GetDataItems();
             DataContext = this;
        }

        private ObservableCollection<Combination> GetDataItems()
        {
            //Here load all of your individual data structure
            //Eg
            var items = new List<Combination>
                            {
                                new Combination(new Bank {AccountNo = 112, AccountName = "somename"},
                                                new Cheque {ChequeDate = DateTime.Now, ChequeNo = 234562}),
                                new Combination(new Bank {AccountNo = 132, AccountName = "name"},
                                                new Cheque {ChequeDate = DateTime.Now, ChequeNo = 215562}),
                                new Combination(new Bank {AccountNo = 212, AccountName = "someother"},
                                                new Cheque {ChequeDate = DateTime.Now, ChequeNo = 114562})
                            };

            return new ObservableCollection<Combination>(items);
        }

        private ObservableCollection<Combination> _dataItems;

        public ObservableCollection<Combination> DataItems
        {
            get { return _dataItems; }
            set { _dataItems = value; }
        }
    }

    public class Combination
    {
        public Combination(Bank bk, Cheque cq)
        {
            ChequeNo = cq.ChequeNo;
            ChequeDate = cq.ChequeDate;
            AccountName = bk.AccountName;
            AccountNo = bk.AccountNo;
        }

        public int ChequeNo { get; set; }
        public DateTime ChequeDate { get; set; }
        public int AccountNo { get; set; }
        public String AccountName { get; set; }
    }

    public class Cheque
    {
        public int ChequeNo { get; set; }
        public DateTime ChequeDate { get; set; }
    }

    public class Bank
    {
        public int AccountNo { get; set; }
        public String AccountName { get; set; }
    }
```

And finally bind it to your ListView

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml" xmlns:WpfApplication1="clr-namespace:WpfApplication1"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">

    <Grid>
        <ListView x:Name="lvac" HorizontalAlignment="Left" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=DataItems}" VerticalAlignment="Top">
            <ListView.View>
                <GridView>
                    <GridViewColumn Width="100"  Header="Cheque Num" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=ChequeNo}" />
                    <GridViewColumn Width="100" Header="Ch. date" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=ChequeDate}" />
                    <GridViewColumn Width="100" Header="Account Name" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=AccountName}" />
                    <GridViewColumn Width="100" Header="Account No" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=AccountNo}" />
                </GridView>
            </ListView.View>
        </ListView>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

So the result would be something like below
[image]

Comment: I am new to MVVM.So i have copy paste this code in new wpf project ...but it is not showing out put data in list view ...Please tell me what other thing i need to get the display that you have shown ? some kind of command file or INotifyPropertychanged code ?

Comment: @user3012262; I updated the code. You were missing a line in constructor, which assign the datacontext of the window. "DataContext = this"

Answer (score 0):

You cannot bind single grid to multiple item-sources at one time. What you might do is create a new class and create BankAccount and Bank objects in it and bind the object of this new class to your gridview.

Comment: please tell me commands to bind multiple tables at time with list view .

Comment: Create a new class with Bank and BankAccount objects in it, lets say you name that class to BankEntity, create an object of BankEntity and bind it to the grid. 
It would be something like this
lvac.ItemSource = bankEntityObject;

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possbile. The answer would be to have a proper ViewModel providing all the necessary information for the ListView.

Please take a look at the links here:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model_View_ViewModel

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd419663.aspx

MVVM is the right way to go with this.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using **MVVM** pattern (which is very common in WPF), you have to implement some "transit" properties in ViewModel to exchange data between multiple bindings in custom way